# Can't Access Local Static Resource Flask Application Deployed on Apache2

Tags: flask, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

I've deployed a simple Flask Application on Apache2 in Ubuntu 16.04 x64(Alibaba Cloud) with mod_wsgi. I'm using mysql as my database server on the same ubuntu server instance.

I've kept my local static resource file in the static directory of the application. Whenever I call remote resources it comes nicely but same thing is not happening for my local resources(i.e. css files, images etc).

I know by default the static directory is static for flask. In my local computer, everything works fine. 
Here is how I'm trying to get static resources from jinja2 template.

```
<div id="loader-div2"><img src={{ url_for('static',filename='simple_gif.gif') }}></div>
```

And in my view(myapp.py) to the jinja2 template, here is the url endpoint:

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='/static')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('my_template.html')
# I've called this at the end
app.run(debug=False)
```

In my wsgi file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from myapp import app as application
```

Folder structure

```
/var/www/FlaskApp
|-myapp.py
|-flaskapp.wsgi
| |-static
|    |-simple_gif.gif
| |-templates
|   |-my_template.html
```

**Recap of the problem:**
Can't access static resource in Apache2 server but can access in local machine. I always get 404 status if I try to do http://XX.XX.XX.XX/static/simple_gif.gif. For the same reason I can't access css files as well back there. I'm badly stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

**Edit**
Here is the config for apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 127.0.0.1
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/static
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/static/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined  </VirtualHost>
```

**Edit2**
I've solved the problem. It was another apache conf file which was confusing apache. Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: What is the Apache configuration where you have setup Apache to host your static files? If you haven't set it up, see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#hosting-of-static-files

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I think I have followed the procedure documented there long before. Is it about trailing slash or something wrong the edit I've posted as the config? By the way, thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: FYI, I've added a trailing slash as well for the static alias, still having the same issue.

Comment: What do you get for ``ls -las /var/www/FlaskApp/static``?

Comment: BTW, for Apache 2.4, instead of ``Order/Allow`` directives, you should use ``Require all granted``. This is not likely to be the issue as you have compat module loaded as well so old work, but if it hadn't you would have got an error when Apache started.

Comment: Also, is this the only ``VirtualHost``?

Comment: I had another config file (000-default.conf) where the static directory was pointing towards different location. Actually, 000-default.conf was the file which was running the server block in my case. I had completely missed that. I've changed the static alias and it's working pretty well. Thanks a lot for your help @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Answers to your last two questions:
ls -las /var/www/FlaskApp/static (I get all the  static files). Only VirtualHost : Yes